# Unable to update value based on another field in xeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am using angular xeditable form.I am trying to create a scenario where a text field value is being automatically updated when another field is been filled . It works well in plain angular. I try to use it in angular xeditable , its not working.

My html will look like this.

```
<a href="#" editable-text="a">
<a href="#" editable-text="b">
```

My controller will look like this .

```
$scope.a = "jp";
$scope.b = $scope.a;
```

I have enclosed a sample http://jsfiddle.net/pravinkumart/BfL9D/1/

Please some one help me to fix it.

Comment: You want to update the second field, while you're typing in the first?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. xeditable updates the model after the it has been saved. What do you want to accomplish? Perhaps there are other alternatives to reach your goal.

Comment: ok. This is what i need... 1) Type something in text box1. 2) Based on text in text box1 , some functions will be processed and it will return value for text box2. 3) Text box2 should show the value.